# SmartGWT: Validate DynamicForm locally and on server-side

Tags: java, smartgwt, smartclient

I'm using `ValuesManager` (can link multiple `DynamicForms` into one request) but to simplify this example let's assume I'm using simple `DynamicForm` with some `DataSource`.

When on `DynamicForm` I run method `validate()` it's use Client-Side Validators I wrote for my purposes. That's ok. But also I want to validate data on Server-Side.

I don't want to use method `saveData()` because I want to show pop-up window with confirmation entered data.

Is there any way to force ServerSide validation without calling `saveData` ?

PS. `setUseLocalValidators(false)` (on DataSource object) seems doesn't change this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a dataSource you can call

> validateData(values[, callback, requestProperties])

[Smartclient 8.3 documentation DataSource.validateData](http://www.smartclient.com/docs/8.3/a/b/c/go.html#method..DataSource.validateData)

I use Smartclient on the client-side only but I've used this to call my own server-side validation.

I'm sorry I don't have any sample code available.

Comment: Simple... ;)  Intuitive :) 
`validate()` on `ValuesManager` makes Client-side validation on fields in `DynamicForms` and  `validateData` validate value on `DataSource`. Do You know any method to validate all fields in `DataSource` no one by one ?

Comment: I'm still trying to track down my example but I think it submits the entire record. `dataSource.validateData(dynamicForm.getValues(),"if (OK) {dynamicForm.saveData();}",{actionURL:"<validationurl>"}) `

Comment: Thanks @WBAR. I'm not update to speed on it all.  I hope it's all working out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try overriding validate of your `DynamicForm` and add inside the new method code calling the server validation code?